# How to delete instantly a await message from the channel

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord.js

I would like to delete instantly a awaitmessage from the channel. In this example, I would like to delete REASON.

```
await message.channel.send("Why do you want to ban this user?");
const REASON = (await message.channel.awaitMessages(res => message.content, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ["time"]
})).first().content;
```

How can I add this to delete REASON ?

```
.then(message => {
message.delete({ timeout: 30000 })
});
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Do you even know why you are using `await`?

Comment: Yes because I want to collect informations after a command. I just want to remove the await messages from the channel so that they don't pollute.

Comment: I'm lost then. Seems incorrect usage of `await`

Comment: Admittedly, i would have to learn more about `await`. I would think it would force synchronous. I will upvote so someone knowledgeable can see this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like that:

```js
await message.channel.send("Why do you want to ban this user?");
        const REASON = (await message.channel.awaitMessages(res => res.content, {max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ["time"]})
            .then(collected => collected.first().delete())
        );
```

Comment: It's working ! I add REASON.content to display the message :)